# How to get value for Number of Lines in a Street Address that have been set in magento 2 configuration

Tags: magento2, helper, magento2.3.5, magento2.3.5-p2, street-address

I am using Magento 2.3.5-p2

I know that in Magento 2, the Street address configuration is not able to be changed through admin by going to

Stores > Settings > Configuration > Customers > Costumer Configuration > Name and Address Options > Number of Lines in a Street Address

[image]

now my task is that I am required to retrieve value of **Number of Lines in a Street Address** being set above to below file so that I can create some condition

**vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Address/FormPost.php**

what helper or object that I needed to use to be able to get the value of **Number of Lines in a Street Address** being set

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own helper like:

```
<?php

namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Helper;

use \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{

    const CONFIG_ADDRESS_NUMBER_OF_LINES = 'customer/address/street_lines';

    /**
     * @var ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getAddressNumberOfLines()
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::CONFIG_ADDRESS_NUMBER_OF_LINES, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
    }
}
```

And inject the helper to your block or controller or by object manager:

```
$helper = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\MyVendor\MyModule\Helper\Data::class);
echo $helper->getAddressNumberOfLines();
```

P.S.S you can also direct the first code to your block or controller if you dont want to used helper
Sample Code via Object Manager

```
$scopeConfig = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface::class);
$streetLines = $scopeConfig->getValue('customer/address/street_lines', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
echo $streetLines;
```

P.S. using Object Manager is not advisable and you should inject it

*you can find the config path here: vendor/magento/module-customer/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

*config default values was set here: vendor/magento/module-customer/etc/config.xml

you can get others path by opening the system.xml

**E.g.** customer/address/street_lines

- **customer** is the section id
- **address** is the group id
- **street_lines** is the field id

Comment: Wow, thank you, great explanation, this is so easy to understand and implemented

Comment: Glad it helps you .

Comment: If I want to get the value to be put into the shipping.js source code what is the step need to be done

Comment: May I know what it means by should inject Object Manager and how do I change the code if I don't want to use the Object Manager

Comment: If you don't want to used object manager, you should inject it on your __construct.


**Objec Manager:**
`$scopeConfig = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface::class);`

**Via Inject**
`protected $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }`